# Wicket setResponsePage() inside onBeforeRender()

Tags: java, wicket

I have a web application based on Apache Wicket. I have a problem with the usage of the method onBeforRender() of a web page. I need to use this method to intercept the creation of a page, and redirect the user to another page. If I use setResponsePage inside the onBeforeRender, the page is aniway rendered. 
How Can I implement my desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(SomePage.class);
```

As it is an exception it should prevent any other code(=rendering) from being executed.

I'm not sure why you are redirecting. My guess is that it's an authorization topic. Then you might want to check out the [IAuthorizationStrategy](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_authorizations). It's described in the official Wicket docu. They have a very good documentation over there with lots of best practises and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Which `org.apache.wicket.settings.RequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy` do you use ? I believe your problem can happen only with `org.apache.wicket.settings.RequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy#ONE_PASS_RENDER`.

Try to use `#onInitialize()` or `#onConfigure()` instead.

Comment: I used  super.onBeforeRender();
       
            throw new NonResettingRestartException(PrenotazioneListaPage.class);                            when throws the exception, the application redirect correctly